# How to display a default value on a page in react Native

Tags: react-native, react-redux, reactive-programming, react-native-ios

I am displaying content on the page on click of a drop-down button. I want to set some default value on the page irrespective of the dropdown button click and it should change when clicked on the drop-down button. Is there any way of doing it. Please Help.

My dropdown has 4 items. I want to display the first item as default. I have written an onclick event for it and for every onclick, I am fetching a service.

```
async onChangeText(apiurl) {
        this.setState({
            refreshing: false
        });
        let paramUrl;
        this.state.data.forEach(eachUrl => {
            if (apiurl === eachUrl.displayName) {
                paramUrl = eachUrl.apiurl;
            }
        });
        const res = await getResult(paramUrl);
        this.setState({ listItems: res.data });
    }
    My dropdown looks like this
      <Dropdown
                        data={this.state.data}
                        label='Select'
                        fontSize={15}
                        valueExtractor={({ displayName }) => displayName}
                        itemPadding={10}

                        onChangeText={this.onChangeText.bind(this)}
                    />
```

Comment: Which 3rd party lib are you using for `Dropdown`

Comment: Hi Aravind, I am using react-native-material-dropdown

Comment: can you try this prop `dropdownPosition={1}`

Comment: @Aravind S, I am able to set the value as option 1, but I do not know how the service I am fetching on click of that button should be displayed in a default manner. Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: i dont understand by saying - I do not know how the service I am fetching on click of that button should be displayed in a default manner.

Comment: On click of every drop-down button, I am fetching data from a service and displaying in a view. But I want one of those services to be displayed as default in the view before i click any options in the dropdown @Aravind S

Comment: then hit your api on `componentDidMount` with the dropdown value you needed...does that make sense?

Comment: I am new to react and react native.. could you be a bit more clear... @Aravind S

Comment: can you share you entire component code in question to see how you done it